# Possible to toggle/animate between two sizes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a small div that is initially styled to 60x60.  I have created click event that animates the expansion of the div:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function () {
    $(this).animate(
    {
        width: "350px",
        height: "300px"
    }, 500);
}
```

I would like to reverse this animation if someone clicks the div again.  Is there anyway to toggle between the original size and the expanded size (still using the animate function) with each click?

I found the toggleClass function but I don't think this will work with animiate.

You can see a basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NS9Qp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#myDiv").toggle(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: "350px",
        height: "300px"
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: "60px",
        height: "60px"
    }, 500);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/vfeQT/).

The jQuery `toggle()` function allows you to define two or more functions to cycle through on each mouse click. In this case, the first one (triggered on the first click) expands the div and the second one (triggered on the second click) resets it. On the third click, it starts back at the first one, and so on.

More about `toggle()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Comment: I have this exact code but it does not register the click and when added through the inspector simply hides via display:none. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

just to be different :

```
var size=[];
$("#cornerBox").click(function(){
    $(this).width() >= 350 ? size=[60, 60] : size=[350, 300];
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: size[0], height: size[1] },500);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NS9Qp/1/

Comment: Indeed I did, I just copied the code from the question, but I guess Abe can add a stop if it's needed himself, but the animation is pretty fast, so unless someone clicks really fast a number of times on purpose it's not really needed for this one.

Comment: True, but I cannot see a reason why someone would need this without stop()? I see many times people double clicking links on internet, like they do on folders in there OS ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using jQuery UI's animated toggleClass effect: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

super simple code:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hidden", 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not hardcode css styles (in my example I used inline css for myDiv element, put this in css files).

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background:red; width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = $('#myDiv');
    div
        .attr('defWidth', div.width())
        .attr('defHeight', div.height())
        .toggle(function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({width: "350px", height: "300px"}, 500);
            }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({width: $(this).attr('defWidth'), height: $(this).attr('defHeight')}, 500);
            }
        );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do for cases like this, is store a transformation array.

```
var transforms = { 'height0': 60, 'width0': 60, 'height1': 300, 'width1': 350};
```

Then, store a toggle between 0 or 1, and use the corresponding values for the animation.

EDIT: combine this with the previous example of toggle, and you've got yourself a solid working solution!

Comment: This parameters should be stored in css and not hardcoded in javascript.